# Cannot infer type arguments for hashmap<>

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am getting

```
   Cannot infer type arguments for java.util.HashMap<>
```

for the following code

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "x");
        map.put(2, "y");
        map.put(3, "x");
        map.put(4, "z");

  //the following line has error
        Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> reverseMap = new java.util.HashMap<>(map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue)).values().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.get(0).getValue(),
                        item -> new ArrayList<>(item.stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList())))); 
        System.out.println(reverseMap);

    }

}
```

What went wrong and Can anyone Explain me this ?
I have checked for proper imports and found out that I am importing java.util.hashmap and none other. 
Still the pesky error is buging me.

[image: The Error Persists]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's a bug in `ecj` (eclipse compiler), you can work around it and add more type information :

```
item -> new ArrayList<Integer>(item.stream().map(Entry::getKey)
```

See how I've added `ArrayList<Integer>`.

It compiles fine with `javac-8 and 9`.

And btw seems like there is a simpler way to do things:

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Entry::getValue,
                    HashMap::new,
                    Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Indeed, IntelliJ IDEA compiles the original code without errors.

Comment: I filed [a bug against ecj](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=527742) where you may follow the process towards a fix.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the error disappeared after adding  `import java.util.Map;` :

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcInsert;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;


    public void saveFooOrder(Foo foo, long orderId) {

         Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
                                         /*^^^^ Error was here: Cannot 
                                                infer type arguments for HashMap<>*/
            values.put("fooOrder", orderId);
            values.put("foo", foo.getId());
            orderFooInserter.execute(values);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is not completed, and you are missing a `)`

try doing:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1, "x");
        map.put(2, "y");
        map.put(3, "x");
        map.put(4, "z");

        Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> reverseMap = new java.util.HashMap<>(map.entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue)).values().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(item -> item.get(0).getValue(),
                        item -> new ArrayList<>(item.stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toList())))));
        System.out.println(reverseMap);
     }
}
```

this produce the output

```
{x=[1, 3], y=[2], z=[4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the code is related to the Java version.
I get the same error with this running locally on IntelliJ and deploying using Jenkins.

I had to add this to my pom.xml file to fix the issue

```
<properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
```